# Font-face works in mailchimp template preview, but not in the e-mail itself

Tags: html, css, font-face, mailchimp

I was really excited when I finally got my custom fonts working in a custom Mailchimp template.

I added the following to the head of the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://eberhardtsmith.com/d/wp-content/themes/blankslate/font-face/fonts.css">
```

That worked, until I use the template in a campaign, and everywhere shows the fallback font (Safari, Firefox, Mailbox for iPhone, Gmail tested).

Seems like the HTML isn't rendering the  in the head of the template when it's in use. Anyone have any experience getting mailchimp  to work?

Comment: Most email clients strip or block CSS links, but some will allow inline CSS through.

Comment: @j08691I'll try inline and see if that works!

Comment: @j08691 it's working as inline styles!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to choose a mail-safe font. Check out this [blog post](http://blog.campaignmaster.co.uk/2013/01/10/email-101-email-safe-fonts/).
Emails are quite limited in what you can do in terms of styling.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to reccomendation from @j08691, I was able to get the fonts working using *inline styles* and not `<link>`.

However, the fonts only display on e-mail clients which support @font-face.
Otherwise, it uses fallback font.